# How to change a file path in R with a constant?

Tags: r, path, paste

I have a script that exports *.csv files to a folder. I will achieve that I can define at the beginning of the script the name of the experiment for e.g. name <- PS3 and this changes all the file paths e.g

```
write.csv(Data, file="Measurements/UV-Vis_Experiments/E48/******_Result.csv")
```

with the result:

```
write.csv(Data, file="Measurements/UV-Vis_Experiments/E48/PS3_Result.csv")
```

Answer (score 5):

Set a variable and `paste()` the filename together:

```
foo <- "PS3"
write.csv(Data,
  file=paste0("Measurements/UV-Vis_Experiments/E48/",foo,"_Result.csv"))
```

Comment: `file.path` is also a nice function to do that.

Comment: No, sorry, that was not a good idea, `paste0` and `sprintf` are really better functions to achieve what is asked!

Answer (score 1):

Can also be achieved using sprintf

```
foo<-"PS3"
write.csv(DataObj,file=sprintf("%s.csv",paste("Measurements/UV-Vis_Experiments/E48/",foo,sep="_")))
```